# Files Changed Since

Tags: datetime, file, ntfs

Short of recursing and comparing dates of files/directories, is there a better way of getting a list of all files and directories that have been changed on an NTFS drive since a particular date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think that's what NTFS [Change Journals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363798%28VS.85%29.aspx) are good for.

Comment: With one caveat: a USN journal must already exist for you to get this data. Windows does not create one by default on XP and most server SKUs, but on Win7, it'll be there. Dunno about Vista.